# How to add nested DIV in BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

All I want is to add a DIV to the "container DIV" in my HTML file but BS4 is keep doing after or before that tag! I can't make it work to go INSIDE the container.

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg1"><img src="1.png"></div>
        <div class="bg2"><img src="2.png"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my Python:

```
with open("/var/www/html/index.html") as inf:
    html = inf.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    prettyHTML = soup.prettify()   #prettify the html
    children = soup.div.container
    
addMyDiv= soup.new_tag('div', id='NewDIV') # create the DIV
soup.html.body.insert(1, addMyDiv)

with open("/var/www/html/index.html", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(prettyHTML))
```

It just keeps adding the DIV after "container"
How can I force it to add inside of CONTAINER?